# How to activate pagination for ls command?

Tags: command-line, ls

What is the equivalent option for the `ls` command to activate pagination as in DOS the `dir /p` does?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There's no straightforward equivalent in `ls` itself, but there's the [`less`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less) utility, which will format the output of any command as seperate pages, scrollable by line or page:
**`ls -C | less`**

Where `-C` triggers column display. Use `lah` as arguments (`ls -lah`) to get a **l**ine by line display with **a**ll files being displayed (include hidden ones), and **h**uman readable filesizes.

- **To get colours to show up properly**, you need to add the `--color=always` argument to `ls`, and the `-R` argument on less*:

  **`ls -C --color=always | less -R`**

  [image]
  *this shows 'ls -ah --color=always | less -R'*

In contrast to [`more`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?more), [`less`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less) will let you scroll through the output. It's also a bit faster for very large listings.

The pipe works like this:

Every program has input and output, a pipe redirects the output of one program (ls) to the input of another program (less). And less simply expects input which it then formats.

- A more old-school dos equivalent would be [`pg`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/upg.htm):

  ```
  ls | pg
  ```

You can also

- Use `ls | head` or `ls | tail` to display only the first or last part of the output
- Use `watch "ls"` to keep the display open, updating it every few seconds to watch changes
- Use `banner $(ls)` if you're sitting really far away from the screen. (;

---

- If you find all of that too long to remember, you can set up an [*alias*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/alias.html) for it:

  Open `~/.bash_aliases` with a text editor and add something like this to it:

  ```
  alias lsp="ls -ah --color=always | less -R"
  ```

  (this is a script that is run every time a new virtual terminal is started up, you should set up all your permanent aliases there)

  Now you can just type `lsp`, or whatever name you choose.

  If you want to be able to pass **further arguments** to your alias, we need to define a function *instead:*

  ```
  lsp(){ ls -ah --color=always "$@" | less -R; }
  ```

  A function, principally looking like this: `name(){ commands; };` can accept arguments, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on. `$@` means *"every argument, if any"*.

  You can now run something like `lsp *.py`, `lsp -C`, and so on. We insert the arguments at the point where they get passed to ls. We could also have inserted $* for less, if it were the important command. You can see all of ls' arguments at [`man ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) (worth a read).

---

*: The reason for this is, that whenever you Pipe something, it detects a Terminal (actually the other program) not capable of displaying colour. "--color=always" forces ls to ignore this. The -R switch makes less repaint the screen, [escaping the colours](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299) properly.

Comment: thanks great answer, exactly the part with the alias came to my mind when i saw the long commandline. the only disadvantage by creating the alias is that using a wildcard filter like *.pdf this isn't possible? perhaps does there exist also a solution for this?

Comment: Everything is possible ;-) I added the bit about arguments, I somehow didn't think of it earlier.

Comment: you gave more than expected :) thanks for the detailed answer. P.S. do you know if there are differences between bash and fish that somehow prevent this alias argument passing method from working in fish? i got the alias without the argument option to work here.

Comment: I've never used fish; go ahead and ask a question about what the differences are. It'll be very interesting. Note though that alias is not a program, but built in to bash.

Comment: Ok, here http://askubuntu.com/questions/19728/differences-between-fish-and-bash-to-pass-commandline-arguments-to-alias-function the new question starts, thanks again for your helpful answers so far.

Comment: `alias lsp='_(){ ls -ah --color=always $* | less -R; }; _'` don't put a function in an alias, just write a function in the first place: `lsp(){ ls -ah --color=always "$@" | less -R; }`. Also, it's always wrong to use `$*`.

Comment: @geirha, all right, I've edited the answer, and it's now correct. Could you explain why it's always wrong to use `$*`?

Comment: `$*` and `$@` do the exact same thing. They expand to `$1 $2 $3 ...`. Quoted, however, `"$@"` expands to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...` while `"$*"` expands to `"$1 $2 $3 ..."` (that is, all arguments into one string, using the first character of `IFS` as separator). http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if there is some ls command for pagination. However, you may use a pipe and `less`, like this:

```
ls | less
```

And use q to exit.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ls | less` or `ls | more`. The second one is close to the DOS version.

Comment: Is there perhaps another method? because the disadvantage is for me that the colorization of the shell isn't active when using a pipe?

Comment: Try `ls --color=always -C | less -R`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'alias ls="ls --color=always"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
echo 'lsc(){ ls -C "$@" | less -R; }' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bashrc
```

[Result running `lsc` in a terminal](https://i.imgur.com/VtWZkK1.gifv)

Answer (score 0):

Pagination can be done by using the following command.

```
$ ls
```

Above command will print the out in a scrollable format.

```
$ ls | pager
```

Above command will print the out in a paginated format.

**Some extra pointers:-**

- Use spacebar to go to next page.
- Use q to exit the pagination.