# What do each of the colors of files/folders returned from running the ls command mean in gnome terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color Meanings in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/color-meanings-in-terminal)

When I run the

```
# ls
```

command, a list of files and folders are returned.

Some of them are colored blue, others green.

I'm new to terminal and just wanted to know if there were other colors and what each color says about the file or folder.