# What does the l command do?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, alias, ls

There is a command `l` available on my machine which appears to do nothing.  `which l` also produces no output. Is this a real command, and does it actually do anything?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`l` is an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) for `ls -CF`, which **behaves differently from plain `ls`**.

## `-C`

`-C` makes `ls` print output in column form. When [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdout#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is a terminal (rather than being redirected to a file or non-terminal device, or piped to another command), `-C` is implied. So running `ls -C` is the same as running `ls`. But they are *not* equivalent when `ls` is redirected or piped. For example:

```
ek@Kip:~/firefox$ ls
application.ini             libfreebl3.chk    libxpcom.so
blocklist.xml               libfreebl3.so     libxul.so
chrome                      libmozalloc.so    mozilla-xremote-client
chrome.manifest             libmozsqlite3.so  omni.ja
components                  libnspr4.so       platform.ini
crashreporter               libnss3.so        plugin-container

...

ek@Kip:~/firefox$ ls | less

application.ini
blocklist.xml
chrome
chrome.manifest
components
crashreporter

...
```

In contrast, `ls -C` (or `-l`) outputs in column form regardless of what kind of device `stdout` is. `ls -C | less` looks like the top output (but paged by [`less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/less.1.html), of course).

## `-F`

The main visible difference between `ls` and `l` is due to the `-F` flag, which causes `ls` to append symbolic suffixes (called indicators) to the entries it displays. These indicators identify what kind of file or directory they are.

Compare this to the output of the first `ls` command above:

```
ek@Kip:~/firefox$ ls -F
application.ini             libfreebl3.chk     libxpcom.so*
blocklist.xml               libfreebl3.so*     libxul.so*
chrome/                     libmozalloc.so*    mozilla-xremote-client*
chrome.manifest             libmozsqlite3.so*  omni.ja
components/                 libnspr4.so*       platform.ini
crashreporter*              libnss3.so*        plugin-container*

...
```

Here:

- `/` means the entry is a directory.
- `*` means the entry is a normal file and is executable (i.e., has executable [permissions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=execute%20permissions)).
- The absence of any indicator means the entry is a normal file that is not executable.

There are several other indicators:

- `@` means the entry is a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (see also [`man symlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man7/symlink.7.html)).
- `|` means the entry is a [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) device (remember, [many resources in Unix-like OSes are represented by filesystem entries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)).
- `=` means the entry is a [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).
- `>` means the entry is a [door](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_%28computing%29).

The `--classify` flag and `--indicator-style=classify` are equivalent to `-F`.

***Source:** [GNU Coreutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/), [Section 10.1.5 General output formatting](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#General-output-formatting)*

## In conclusion, `l` (`ls -CF`) is similar to but *not the same* as `ls`.

It's also good to keep in mind:

#### The same text can be both a regular command and an alias.

This is commonly used to specify options that are widely considered both highly useful and harmless, such as automatic colorization (where color is applied when `stdout` is unredirected or is a terminal, so the escape codes specifying colors are virtually guaranteed not to be misinterpreted).

#### By this principle, `ls` is itself an alias.

```
ek@Kip:/$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

So what command *really* gets executed when you run `l`? *This one:*

```
/bin/ls --color=auto -CF
```

1. The shell ([`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html)) resolves commands that don't contain a `/` to the first match appearing in [`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), which in Ubuntu for `ls` is `/bin/ls`.
2. Aliases can contain aliases. Alias resolution is not [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) (an alias cannot call itself, though it can call a regular command that has the same name). But it does support [nesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_%28computing%29).

So `l` resolves to `ls -CF` which resolves to `ls --color=auto -CF`.

#### Aliases can be changed.

These aliases exist because they're set up that way by default, but every user can change their aliases. See [`man alias`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/alias.1posix.html), [Chapter 25](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) and [Appendix M](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html) in the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, and [How save my "alias" entries forever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194111/how-save-my-alias-entries-forever).

***Related:** [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/color-meanings-in-terminal)*

Answer (score 6):

Actually both `ls` and `l` are equal

```
raja@badfox:~/Pictures$ l
des.png
Screenshot from 2012-09-22 19:37:03.png
Screenshot from 2012-09-22 19:37:11.png
Screenshot from 2012-09-22 19:37:12.png
Untitled.png
raja@badfox:~/Pictures$ ls
des.png
Screenshot from 2012-09-22 19:37:03.png
Screenshot from 2012-09-22 19:37:11.png
Screenshot from 2012-09-22 19:37:12.png
Untitled.png
```

why means there is a in-built system alias causing for this . if you want to see , open your terminal and type `alias` then you will get output like this

```
raja@badfox:~/Pictures$ alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias lock='gnome-screensaver-command -l'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias sms='php .sms.php'
raja@badfox:~/Pictures$
```

Comment: Mystery solved :)

Comment: @Alison `l` and plain `ls` are *not* the same--they just *happened* to produce the same output for those particular files, since none were directories, executable, symlinks, or device nodes (and standard output was a terminal).

Comment: You can see, `alias l='ls -CF'`, so it's not the same. Also, if you want to get more succinct output, you can run `alias l`.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, `type l`:

```
l is aliased to `ls -alF'
```

(see also [What does the la command do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863528/whats-the-difference-between-ls-and-la-why-do-they-give-the-same-output/863626#863626))