# What do the symbols like =, * and | in the output of "ls -F" mean?

Tags: command-line, files, ls

I am working on creating a 'cheat sheet' of shell commands. I am currently researching the `ls` command and its flags. For the `-F` flag I know what the majority of the appended indicators mean but for; `=` and `|` I can't find any information.

Could someone please tell me what these commands mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the l command do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191746/what-does-the-l-command-do) ([my answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/246208/22949) explains what all those symbols mean). On the other hand, that's considerably more general, so if you answer this as @Aditya suggests, it probably doesn't need to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Out of interest is this 'cheat sheet' going to be/is published ?

Comment: @pl1nk no, it was for Uni. If you need help with commands view the site I have in my answer

Comment: See also: [Unix & Linux: What do the symbols displayed by ls -F mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82358/114401)

Answer (score 22):

I believe you're talking about *indicators* presented by `ls -F`. From the manpage of `ls`:

```
-F, --classify
   append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries

[...]

--indicator-style=WORD
   append indicator with style WORD to entry names: none (default), slash (-p),
   file-type (--file-type), classify (-F)
```

To get an overview of the meaning of these indicators, we have to dive into the `info` page as suggested at the bottom of the manpage (`info coreutils 'ls invocation'`):

```
`-F'
`--classify'
`--indicator-style=classify'
     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append `*'.  The file
     type indicators are `/' for directories, `@' for symbolic links,
     `|' for FIFOs, `=' for sockets, `>' for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.  Do not follow symbolic links listed on the command
     line unless the `--dereference-command-line' (`-H'),
     `--dereference' (`-L'), or
     `--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir' options are specified.
```

*Above is an excerpt taken from the 'General output formatting' section. Go there directly using `info coreutils 'General output formatting'`.*

### TL;DR

- `*` for executables
- `/` for directories
- `@` for [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)
- `|` for [FIFOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)
- `=` for [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)
- `>` for [doors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_%28computing%29)
- (nothing) for regular files