# What's the difference between ls and la? Why do they give the same output?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ls, output

I entered `la` accidentally instead of `ls` to view the contents of a directory and it produces exactly the same output as `ls`...

Why is this? Surely it doesn't make sense to have two commands that do the exact same thing.

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109216/l-ls-la-what-are-the-differences-and-are-there-more-of-these-commands

Comment: Just `type la`. And you'll get it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`la` is an alias to `ls -A` defined in `~/.bashrc` file in Ubuntu.

It only shows the same output if you have no hidden files or directories.

`ls -A` shows hidden files and directories.

Comment: More like "it does not *necessarily* show the same output", since if you don't have any hidden files (those starting with a dot) besides . and .., the output will be the same.

Comment: That is true. Updated.

Comment: Note that `ls -A` is different to `ls -a` - the latter will show the `.` and `..` meaning this directory and containing directory respectively.

Answer (score 14):

`la` is defined as an alias in Ubuntus `~/.bashrc` file together with a few others. `la` is simply an `ls -A` as you can see in the following snippet from the `~/.bashrc`

```
# this alias is defined earlier to grant colored output
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias li='ls -lF'
```

Answer (score 8):

When in doubt, `type la`.

---

Bash output:

```
la is aliased to `ls -la'
```

Fish output:

```
la is a function with definition
function la --description 'List contents of directory, including hidden files in directory using long format'
    ls -lah $argv
end
```

Answer (score 6):

`ls` is a command, `l` and `la` are most likely aliases which make use of the command `ls`. If you run the command `alias` you can find all the aliases on your system.

```
$ alias | grep -E ' l=| la='
```

This will return all the aliases that match the pattern l=... or la=....

Comment: Or just `alias l la`

Answer (score 4):

They do not produce the same output in all directories.

Create a dotfile with `touch .whatever`, then issue both `la` and `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

`la` is an alias for `ls -A`, as stated by other answers. As such, it can't be used in shell scripts, while `ls` can.

Your computer has multiple aliased commands. A complete list can be obtained by executing `alias`. On my machine it prints this:

```
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'  
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'  
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'  
alias grep='grep --color=auto'  
alias l='ls -CF'  
alias la='ls -A'   
alias ll='ls -alF'   
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

`--color=auto` means colour will be turned off when not printing directly to STDOUT.