# No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py' but it is there in red color

Tags: software-installation, python, python-2.7

While trying to install `denyhosts`, I got this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py'

I verified that `/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py` does exist. As you can also see in below screenshot however that appears in red color (don't know if it is signaling something).

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at file/directory permissions throughout the "chain" to get to the file?  Remember dirs need to have 'x' permission eventhough they are not executable entities, it permits the search to happen.  You could help everybody if you included an ls -ld of the file and each of its directories above it as well as the output of the id -a for the specific user.

Answer (score 1):

A red name in a black background means that a file is a link to a non existent file. Please, see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal) for ls output color meanings.

That means that you probably have moved the linked file or deleted it.

Comment: it was a fresh ubuntu 13.04 install I got on my VPS.. i didn't do anything before this install

Comment: Sometimes VPS images are not default installs. Anyway, this file doesn't exists, you are only looking to a dead symlink.

Comment: +1 & Thanks for clarifying please also indicate how to resolve this so that I can accept answer.

Comment: No idea. For a start you can try to do 'ls -l' to see where is this links pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. What worked was

```
sudo dpkg -a --configure
```

as described in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=709157.