# What does a file that is dark grey in linux mean?

Tags: command-line, themes, colors

From this question on the forum [Color Code Files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal), I learned that some colors mean different things on linux. However, in the answer there wasn't a reference to a file that was dark grey. Here is a picture of a file directory:

[image]

What does the grey color mean? I was just wondering out of curiosity. Does it normally have a special meaning, or is this simply just a color scheme setting particular to my environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ls --color=always | less` and you'll see the raw colour codes. Eg:

```
ESC[0mESC[01;34macESC[0m
ESC[01;34mbinESC[0m
ESC[01;34mBioWareESC[0m
```

It's a bit of a mess but in these cases, they're all `01;34`.

Then all you need to do is look in `$LS_COLORS` for that colour.

```
$ echo $LS_COLORS | grep -Eo '[^:]+=01;34'
di=01;34
```

In my example, they're directories.