# How can I find the difference between a folder and a folder link in Ubuntu?

Tags: symbolic-link

Earlier, I had created some links to another folder using the following command.

```
sudo ln -s path_name link_name
```

These links are looking similar to the folders. I am not able to differentiate between a folder and a link. Is there a way to find the difference between a folder and a link to another folder?

Comment: when i type command ls, i see folder names in different colors. Is the link displayed in blue colour or is the folder displaying in blue color ?

Comment: I m working in terminal.No GUI :( i am not allowed to use  a GUI editor.

Comment: It is the light blue/green ones (see http://askubuntu.com/a/17304/72216)

Comment: thanks that had the answer I was looking for. but do you know any other way around instead of color, like can we find the properties of the folder which shows it is a link and a folder ?

Comment: ls -l shows a `->` is that what you mean?

Comment: waow that's just another great way of what i need, dude seriously make an answer for this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21089/discussion-between-mateen-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: There are no such things as 'folders' and 'folder links'. There are, however, 'directories' and 'symbolic (sym) links'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could recognize a link by either a small arrow (`->`) in the output of `ls -l`:

[image]

or by the distinguished color, also appearing in the output of `ls`, as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17304/72216) (`test2` is the link):

[image]

Comment: this is what known as cut-to-cut answer. Thanks

Comment: or by the "l" at the begining of the line with the permissions

Comment: @Jean-Marie how could I forget to mention, of course! It is in terdon's answer, together with a (large) number of other perfect options.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to see this. First of all, it is indicated in the output of `ls -l`. Note that the directory has a `d` at the beginning of the permissions field while the link has an `l`:

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Feb 13 14:12 bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon    3 Feb 13 14:12 foo -> bar
```

You can also use `file`:

```
$ file bar foo 
bar: directory 
foo: symbolic link to `bar'
```

Another choice is `readlink` which follows symbolic links to their targets:

```
$ readlink foo
bar
```

Running `readlink bar` will return no output (it fails, returning a non-0 exit code), so you can do something like:

```
readlink bar || echo "Not a link!"
```

or

```
readlink foo && "Echo this is a link"
```

Finally, you could also use `find` or the shell itself to list all links:

```
find . -type l
```

or

```
for f in *; do [ -L "$f" ] && echo "$f is a link"; done
```

Comment: waoow there are really lot of ways! thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

Read `man [` (or `man test`)and you will see you can do:

```
for theDir in path_name link_name ; do  
    if [ -L $theDir ] ; then  
        echo "$theDir exists and is a symbolic link"   
    elif [ -d $theDir ] ; then  
        echo "$theDir exists and is a directory"  
    fi  
done
```

I changed the order of the tests, so checking for a directory is done only if `$theDir` is not a link.

Comment: This does not work. `if [ -d $theDir ]` returns true if the link's target is a directory.

Comment: @terdon I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

use `ls -F` .

this will make ls append characters to filenames

`*` for executable files

`/` for directories

`@` for symlinks**

`|` for FIFOs

`>` for doors (whatever this means)

`=` for sockets

regular files don't have classifier at the end.
So in your case you'll see `@` at the end of each symlink name and `/` at the end of real directory.

However if you use `ls -l` you won't see classifiers for symlinks and instead you'll see `->` and link target after that.

You can also use `stat` and `file` to differentiate dirs/symlinks
e.g:

```
$ file a                                                                                                                                                                                     
a: directory

$ file b                                                                                                                                                                                      
b: symbolic link to a

$ stat a                                                                                                                                                                                  
  File: 'a'
  Size: 40          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
 [...]

$ stat b                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File: 'b' -> 'a'
  Size: 1           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
  [...]
```