# xfce4-terminal Color Settings for 'ls' in NTFS Partition Mounted by fstab

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, ntfs, xfce4-terminal

I have Xubuntu 14.04, and I have an NTFS data partition that mounts at startup via fstab. How could I adjust the color settings for xfce4-terminal beyond the GUI options? For example how could I set up specifically the color or font-weight of directories or files for 'ls'? Most importantly for now, I would like to make my partition directories appear exactly as they do in my Xubuntu partition (or at least remove the highlighting). Screen shot posted here. Much thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: You probably have it mounted with masks that allow everyone to write, fixing that should fix the highlighting

Comment: Awesome. That fixed it. That was all I really cared about with the colors. Feel free to add your suggestion as an answer, and I will mark it as solved. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default highlighting of `ls` usually marks folders writable by others with that green background. Therefore you can:

1. Change the `fmask`, `dmask` or `umask` values of the mount point to deny write access to others (should be at least `0002`).
2. See [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal) to know what the colors mean and how to set them. For example:

   ```
   LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow="; export LS_COLORS
   ```

   This should make folders writable by others look the same as others. I wouldn't recommend this, of course.