# When I run ls on my usb drive, every file is in the green text of executable files. Why is this?

Tags: usb-drive, ls

The files are those for general consumption for the most part, pictures, documents, pdfs, etc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because your USB drive has a file system that does not store executable bit permissions, and is being mounted so that all files show up as executable.

A mount option like `showexec` for fat filesystems is supposed to do this: *If  set,  the  execute permission bits of the file will be allowed only if the
              extension part of the name is .EXE, .COM, or .BAT. Not set by default.*

You can check how your drive is mounted with the `mount` command, and `man mount` has lots of info on the different options.

Comment: Interesting. Part of the output of `mount` for the relevant drive is `type vfat (rw,noexec,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000)`

Comment: I tried creating a test fat filesystem (FYI with `head -c 1M > tfile` then `losetup`  & `mkfs.vfat` & `mount`) and using no mount options & remounting with your options, all files display as green with the executable bit set, `ls -l` shows `-rwxr-xr-x`. Adding the `showexec` option with `mount -o remount,showexec` didn't change it, but umount-ing and then mounting with `showexec` DID work, and plain text files were NOT green/executable. `mv`'ing a 5 byte text file to a name ending in `.exe` did not immediately change it to green, but umount & then mounting again DID show only the .exe  green

Answer (score 0):

There is a color scheme in terminal, you might find the below link useful to understand the meaning of those colors

[Terminal color schemes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal)