# My drive become green in the output of 'ls'

Tags: mount

My drive has got a green label (default is blue) because I tried something with `mnt` and `fstab` on my Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Can anybody help me how to change the color to default?
It makes my drive not visible in the explorer in Ubuntu.

Result from `cat fstab`:

[image]

**Edit: Thanks to everyone who answered my question.
My problem has been solved after unmont drive on `mnt` directory.**

Comment: Please post the relevant part of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: okay,  i updated my post with the result of fstab, iam newby on this site  (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What's the output of `cat /proc/mounts`? What are the permission flags on that directory (check with `ls -ld some/path/Bussiness`)? Please post textual program output and text file content as, well, text instead of as an image.

Comment: the output from fstab on my post

Comment: the permissions was drwxrwxrwx

Comment: You have two entries for /dev/sda3. You're trying to mount it in two places

Comment: i tried delete that line use nano but it,s says invalid argumen

Comment: Please don’t post your solution in the question field, post an answer instead. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

The green background color indicates, that the directory is writeable by others.
You can see it by doing:

```
mkdir myDir
mkdir openDir
chmod 777 openDir
ls -l
```

You will see, that `openDir` has a green background, while `myDir` is the "normal" color for directories.

For more info, see [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal)

Comment: but why my drive is not visible on explorer ?

Answer (score -1):

It might be color for owner. you can check it by `dircolors | grep ow`, look for ow marked in red. you can set a different color by adding a line to .bashrc. For example, to make all directories with blue text+underline and no background I added this line: `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=4;94:ow=4;94' ; export LS_COLORS`