# What do link colors mean?

Tags: 16.04, server

[image]

I'm working through https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_manual_deployment.html#_deploying_our_code_manually, trying to set up a django app on an ubuntu 16.04 VPS. I've followed the directions on setting up an nginx config file. Following the directions I have set up a basic nginx config file and put in in /etc/nginx/sites-available/tester. Now I'm trying to symlink it to /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
deploy@server:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo ln -s tester /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tester
```

But I'm suspecting that Something is wrong because the link looks different than the default link.

Also after reloading Nginx with:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

The site did not work. I checked :

```
sudo nginx -T
```

but don't see the config file. What am I doing wrong. What do the colours mean?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls Oh and the red one is pointing to itself.

Comment: Not an NGINX thing, so i've removed that tag.

Comment: @Rinzwind, would you mind explaining how with the ln -s I used above it ended up pointing to itself?