# Filename with red writing and black background with arrow pointing to another file, does anyone know what this means?

Tags: command-line, files, ethereum

Trying to figure out what this means -> see image, any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Terminal output is in link below]

Comment: "symlink to non-existent file", looks like.

Comment: Not really a duplicate as red color, in this case, is a broken link and not an archive.

Comment: Top answer on the linked question has been edited to include this exact situation.

Comment: @Panther did you see https://askubuntu.com/a/17304/158442? Even before the top answer was edited, it included this situation.

Comment: Missed that ooops