# ls color white vs. green

Tags: 16.04, command-line, ls

I tried looking at [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls/17300), but the list doesn't state the color white.

Look at the image below:

[image: Screenshot of Gnome Terminal]

What is the green and what is the white (`libfuse.so` and `libfuse3.so`)?

Comment: I'd guess white is a regular file and green is one with executable permissions set...?

Comment: I've expanded my answer on the linked question to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Green was described the linked answer as:

> **Green**: Executable or recognized data file

*White* seems to be the default color (*0*), which means **Normal (nonfilename) text** and **Regular file**

More info can be found in [man dir colors](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/dir_colors.5.html):

> ISO 6429 color sequences are composed of sequences of numbers
>   separated
>          by semicolons.  The most common codes are:
>
> ```
>            0   to restore default color
>            1   for brighter colors
>            4   for underlined text
>            5   for flashing text
>           30   for black foreground
>           31   for red foreground
>           32   for green foreground
>           33   for yellow (or brown) foreground
>           34   for blue foreground
>           35   for purple foreground
>           36   for cyan foreground
>           37   for white (or gray) foreground
>           40   for black background
>           41   for red background
>           42   for green background
>           43   for yellow (or brown) background
>           44   for blue background
>           45   for purple background
>           46   for cyan background
>           47   for white (or gray) background
>
>    Not all commands will work on all systems or display devices.
>
>    ls uses the following defaults:
>
>    NORMAL    0           Normal (nonfilename) text
>    FILE      0           Regular file
>
>    DIR       32          Directory
>    LINK      36          Symbolic link
>    ORPHAN    undefined   Orphaned symbolic link
>    MISSING   undefined   Missing file
>    FIFO      31          Named pipe (FIFO)
>    SOCK      33          Socket
>    BLK       44;37       Block device
>    CHR       44;37       Character device
>    EXEC      35          Executable file
> ```