# Change Background colour or Permissions for directories in terminal when copy pasted folders from other desktop

Tags: command-line, files, directory, desktop-background

I have copy pasted some directories and files from other computer. Now if i open those files and directories i get a green colour background for directories and in case of files the copy pasted files are in green colour.

How can i remove those green background and those green colour colour code for the copy-pasted files from other computers..?? and get the default colours ..??

Here is the screenshot image of the terminal wherein the folders and files copy-pasted from other computer are looking with different colour.

[image]

Any suggestions..??

Comment: The colours depend on permissions & such. E.g. directories which are writeable for others get a green background (by default). You can see permissions and such with the `ls -l` command.

Comment: Those permissions might be because you copied something from a filesystem which doesn't support permissions (e.g. a DOS-formatted disk using FAT/FAT32).

Comment: @JanC That sounds to me like a perfect answer, would you mind posting it as such? You can add a link to https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls as well to complete it.

Comment: Well, I was not entirely sure what D.H.N wants. Change/remove colours, change permissions, or something else? Maybe he/she can update the question.

Comment: @JanC I have copied the folders/files from other desktop having Ubuntu OS only. I want to change/remove colours, change permissions.

Comment: Even if i copy and paste the files and directories from other system, and then in terminal if i open, the colour should be the default (ie., files should be in white colour and folders in blue colour only...). How can i make this..??