# Where is the python environment in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, 18.04

I am trying to work with PyCharm and it initially gave me an issue of a lack of interpreter. I ran into finding that the Python environment was not in the /bin directory. I am new to programming, but my coworkers have designed their programs according to this path. They said it would be an issue for me to integrate into the systems we work on because of this. Am I misunderstanding the issue, or would there be a problem arising without my python environment being in /bin? 
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps my main issue is it constantly giving me "bash: ./test_script.py: usr/bin/: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" when I create a simple hello world script.

Comment: I wish to work on Python 2.7

Comment: What's the first line of the `test_script.py` file? It sounds like it's the wrong shebang.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried the `where python` command ? It should print you the path to your python. It's possible that yours is in `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: The python interpreters seem to be in the /usr/bin directory, correct. And to be 100% sure, the blue signifies that they are interpreters?

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls) says that blue can be Directory or Symlink

Comment: I think you meant `which python`

Comment: If the python interpreter is not on your path, then `which` isn't going to help, since it searches your path. `whereis` will search for binaries throughout your system regardless of your path and is probably what you want.