# What the "snap" is going on with this symbolic link?

Tags: snap, symbolic-link

I was looking in `/usr/bin` tonight and saw this:

[image: snapd in usr bin.png]

The symbolic link in cyan / red is a curiosity:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          25 Jul 19 04:48 ubuntu-core-launcher -> ../lib/snapd/snap-confine*
```

As I don't use `snapd` yet (Ubuntu 16.04 / Unity Interface) I'm not really concerned but I'm curious if anyone else has encountered this strange coloured link and what it means with all the dangerous looking red?

Comment: Looks like a bug in `ls`. Instead of filling the width of file name, it probably padded `printf()` function to fill the screen width with blanks, but instead of sticking control character to uncolonize the output at the end of filename, it stuck it at the end of the padding.

Comment: If you're asking about the meaning of color, then it probably means  full permissions  for everyone, notice the permissions the link has. There's a post about it on askubuntu somewhere

Comment: From [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/a/884513/178692) *Uncolored with red background: set-user-ID file*

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Could it be what the link points to? `-rwsr-sr-x  root   root   98440  Jul 19 04:48  /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine` Notice the `s` where `x` for execute usually resides for `root` and `group ID`, yet Everyone is set to `x` and not `s`.

Comment: @steeldriver The link left me more confused than the red in my question did :)

Comment: Yes, the `s` bit, that's what the steeldriver's link actually explains. So red because it's SUID program and it can do root things without promoting for password

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Actually it means root runs as the user? http://olivermellinuxacademy.com/blog/rwx-versus-rws/ Plus as you mentioned a bug in `printf` usage.

Answer (score 1):

As [sergiy](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy) mentioned in comments it is a bug with `ls` not filling in colors properly when window size causes a line to wrap to the next.

You can see it here by changing the window size for `sudoedit`:

[image: ls for sudoedit.png]

As for the color red itself it's because root becomes the user due to access permissions:

```
$ llocate /lib/snapd/snap-confine
ACCESS      OWNER  GROUP  SIZE   MODIFIED      NAME (updatdb last ran: 2018-09-26 17:45:05)
-rwsr-sr-x  root   root   98440  Jul 19 04:48  /mnt/clone/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
-rwsr-sr-x  root   root   85832  Nov 30  2017  /mnt/old/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
-rwsr-sr-x  root   root   98440  Jul 19 04:48  /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
```

Notice `root` has access rights `rws` and `group` has access rights `r-s`. Everyone else has `r-x` execute rights. See: [rwx Versus rws](http://olivermellinuxacademy.com/blog/rwx-versus-rws/)

---

Scrolling down further there is another bug example in orange this time:

[image: ls write bug.png]