# How to disable ls colors on ntfs-mounted partitions only?

Tags: ntfs, colors, ls

I love [`ls` colors](https://askubuntu.com/q/17299/80483) and do ***not*** want to disable them *everywhere*, but the `ls` colors are *useless* on `ntfs`-mounted (and probably other similar file systems - like `exfat`) partitions, because **all** files there have 777 permissions. They are also distractive because directories are shown in inverse video and thus have poor contrast.

Is there a way to **selectively** disable colors on some partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mount the `ntfs` partition with better permissions than just 777.

if you add

```
fmask=133,dmask=022
```

to the options section of your fstab entry the drive shouldn't look so weird when viewed with ls. Folders will be 755 and files 644 which matches your home directory.

Unless you need to run executable files from the partition in which case I think 777 is the only way to go.