# Why a script file .sh on ubuntu is not in green as the others?

Tags: scripts

On Ubuntu 20.04 there's a directory with a bunch of .sh files in it. Except one all are in green.
Would someone please tell how that can be and what makes that particular .sh file so special?

Comment: Try and post the output of `ls -l` in the directory. There you can see the permission string, which need to have the `x` (executable) bit. If the file is executable it is colored green by default.

Comment: See [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls)

Answer (score 2):

It is because that file has no execute permission. The `ls` program shows the names of executable files in green. Try listing with `ls -l` - the permissions will be listed to the left of the filenames. `r` means read, `w` means write, and `x` means execute. There are three sets of permissions - a set for the owner of the file, a set for the group associated with the file (`ls -l` also lists these), and a set for "others" which is any user or program. To make the file executable for the owner, you can run `chmod u+x`, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps!