# "bash: cd: /home/marcoluis/.local/bin: Not a directory"

Tags: command-line, 18.04

While trying to install ade(Awesome Development Environment) through Ubuntu Terminal, for a [Autoware.Auto Course](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/autowareclass2020/-/blob/master/lectures/01_DevelopmentEnvironment/devenv.md#docker) , I've ran into a problem while moving the ade executable from "adehome" file to path "~/.local/bin". After the following commands:

```
~/adehome$ mv ade ~/.local/bin
~/adehome$ which ade
```

No directory appears, and by trying to enter such directory, appears the following message:

```
bash: cd: /home/marcoluis/.local/bin: Not a directory
```

How can I retrieve the filepath in order to continue? Or should I just try again the steps given?

Edit: After checking ~/.local filepath list, the following output path is given:

```
$ ls -la ~/.local
total 7828
drwx------  3 marcoluis marcoluis    4096 out 15 14:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 marcoluis marcoluis    4096 out 15 14:22 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 marcoluis marcoluis 7999712 jan 26  2020 bin
drwx------ 14 marcoluis marcoluis    4096 out 15 14:49 share
```

Comment: Did the `~/.local/bin` directory already exist when you did that `mv`? If not, you just renamed your `ade` file to the `bin` file in `~/.local`.

Comment: I am not sure if it existed or not, the video classes say that the file path should exist in any ubuntu machine. Is there anyway I can reverse this?

Comment: Your video classes are mistaken. A stock install of Ubuntu does not include that directory, which would be empty anyway. However, it is trivial to create the directory, and it is very likely that your error can be undone.

Comment: Seems like I did rename the ade file into bin. SO could you tell me whats the best way to proceed?

Comment: @MarcoLuís Create `~/.local/bin` then add to your `$PATH`.

Comment: I ended up moving the file back to adehome, renamed it and then moved it towards the new bin file I created in ~/.local. Just one more dumb question, the bin file that is the ade renamed file appeared green in the ~/.local path. WHat does that mean?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls for an explanation of the colors.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `~/.local/bin` is not a directory, but a large file. The directory likely did not yet exist when you executed the command. In that case, `move` interprets `/bin` as the target filename and thus renames the file `ade` to a file named `bin` under `~/.local`.

It will interpret `/bin` as a directory only if that directory exists. Thus, rename that `bin` file back to `ade`, and create the `bin` directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
```

Then you can move the file to the desired directory:

```
mv ~/.local/ade ~/.local/bin
```

On Ubuntu, the `~/.local/bin` directory will automatically be included in your search PATH if you log out then back in.