# How creating new $PATH works?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to add a path of a program/file into $PATH, but I don't understand the guidelines and finally, it doesn't work either. E.g. [following this guideline](https://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Program-from-the-Command-Line-on-Linux):

- if `export PATH=$PATH:[path/to/program]` is just a temporary solution, why do it for repeatable usage?
- if I add *export* function for the path to *bashrc* and update it, it doesn't work either. And I suspect that it is because we haven't determined the name of the actual file? On the other hand, the error message mentions command: `Command "foo" not found...` so it takes me to the question, how the system determines between commands and programs?

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bashrc` after updating it, what does `echo $PATH` output, and, finally, where is this program located? You should add the directory where the program is located to `PATH`, not the complete path to the script/binary.

Comment: Yes I did `source ~/.bashrc`. `echo $PATH` shows me pathes in the $PATH so the path I have just added is also there: `/juan/diskD/Programy/OpenRefine/openrefine-3.6.0`. The program is located in the *openrefine-3.6.0* directory.

Comment: Is the program file's executable bit set? do the mount options on `/juan/diskD` permit program execution?

Comment: `ls` shows [green color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls), so I expect its executable. Properties read *shell script*. I don't know what are mount options on a specific directory, but I can initiate the program from its mother directory via `chmod a+x *program*` and then `/.*program*`.

Comment: The PATH variable should contain only directory names, so `/path/to/program` should be `/path/to/directory/where/program/is/located/`.

Comment: Well, I have there just directories.

Answer (score 0):

> if export PATH=$PATH:[path/to/program] is just a temporary solution, why do it for repeatable usage?

Like you say, it is a temporary solution for use in only a single session.

> if I add export function for the path to bashrc and update it, it doesn't work either. And I suspect that it is because we haven't determined the name of the actual file?

`.bashrc` is run each time you open an active terminal. If correctly entered in a location of the script that is run, it should work. If you prefer the entry to work always, e.g. also from a script run from a program laucher, or from the Alt+F2 run dialog, add the statement to `.profile` instead. That file is read when you log in.

No, your suspicion is wrong. One a (valid) directory is added to `PATH`, the system will search that directory for a file name matching a command you entered at the terminal prompt.

> so it takes me to the question, how the system determines between commands and programs?

A command is a string you type in the terminal to execute something. It can be a shell builtin, or it can be an executable file. An executable file is a file where the executable bit has been set. It can be a script (bash, python, ...) or binary code. It may be a matter of semantics, but any command corresponds to some programmed code, be it a shell builtin, e.g. `cd` or an executable file to launch, e.g. `gedit`.

You can specify a full pathname to an executable. Then the shell will immediately locate it and (try to) execute it.

If you just type a name, the shell will start searching for something with that name to execute:

1. It checks whether the name corresponds with an internal command, i.e. a "shell builtin". A shell builtin resides in memory as part of your command interpreter, typically `bash` in interactive shells on Ubuntu. `cd`, `pwd`, `echo` and `set` are examples of shell builtins (in bash).
2. Then it goes looking into the hash table, a trick to speed up finding executables. When you just logged in, the hash table is empty.
3. Then it proceeds inspecting each folder in your `PATH`, in the order folders are listed. So if the path is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games`, `/usr/local/sbin` is searched for the string. If it is not found there, the system continues searching in he next directory, `/usr/local/bin` etc. `ls` and `chmod` are example of executables.

You can learn about your commands with the `type` command. For example:

```
$ type man
man is hashed (/usr/bin/man)
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ type chmod
chmod is /usr/bin/chmod
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
```

You can identify and locate external executables with the `which` command:

```
$ which cd
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

Comment: If you add a remark that `.bashrc` is only read for interactive non-login shells and suggest [/etc/profile.d/](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Other_files-1) over `/etc/profile`, you have my upvote :)

Comment: The scope of the question is user account configuration, and I am already saying in non technical language that .bashrc is read each time you open a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't probably need to change your PATH. It is usually good as is. Consider one of other possibilities:

1. Moving the program to one of the directories that are already in PATH, particularly `/home/UserName/.local/bin`.
2. Creating an alias for the program in your shell, so you can execute the program simply by typing it's nice alias.

   ```
   gedit ~/.bash_aliases
   ```

   Add a line like:

   ```
   alias do-it='/path/to/program/program-name'
   ```

   Restart the shell or do `source ~/.bashrc`. Execute using alias:

   ```
   do-it
   ```

   It works as if you've called the program directly:

   ```
   /path/to/program/program-name
   ```